# How to make sprintf fail gracefully?

Tags: php

I had to make a GUI which would allow my client to customise a greeting message. They understood that they would have to use %s to indicate where the user name would be presented. But when too many %s are specified `sprintf` fails with message `Too few arguments`.

Is there an option to either leave excess %s instances in the string or just replace them with an empty string?

```
// $greeting_template === 'Welcome to our site %s. Broken: %s'
$output = sprintf($greeting_template, $user_name);
```

Obviously there are other sprintf formatting templates, those should also fail gracefully.

Comment: I tried using `@sprintf` to ignore warning, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure, that the message template is valid, instead of fixing broken ones

```
if (substr_count($greeting_template, '%s') > 1)
  throw new Exception('Too many placeholders');
```

[`substr_count()`](http://php.net/substr-count)

Or you switch to a completely own string-template format like

```
$greeting_template = 'Welcome to our site {username}. Broken: {username}';
$replacements = array('{username}' => $username);
$message = str_replace(
              array_keys($replacements),
              array_values($replacements), 
              $greeting_template);
```

Comment: this is not what he could be looking for, maybe the template string does need to have %s untouched

Comment: The idea is to catch invalid messages, _before_ they are saved somewhere, at least by the first solution. `sprintf()` makes it difficult to replace placeholder multiple times with the same value. Thats the reason, why I decided to provide a second solution.

Comment: They are not necessarily invalid if the template string needs more %s  untouched

Comment: In this case it is: Multiple placeholders require multiple values (even if they contain the same concrete value). It is by default not possible to replace multiple placeholders with one value, thus when you have just one value, but multiple placeholders, it _is_ invalid. Its not the fault of the OP, or the template, or whoever, its the fault of `printf()`, that treats every single placeholder on its own.

Comment: i am not talking about multiple placehorders. I am talking about a template string that needs some %s to be left untouched (as it may seem from the OP question).

Comment: @KingCrunch thanks this seems like a much cleaner solution. I am sure that my client would rather type a meaningful word instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead?

```
$output = str_replace('%s', $user_name, $greeting_template);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own version of sprintf.

```
function sprintf2(){ // untested
 $args=func_get_args();
 $template=array_shift($args);
 return str_replace( '%s', $args, $template );
}
```

use it like:

```
sprintf2('your template %s. Other %s untouched','User123');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following format:

```
$greeting_template === 'Welcome to our site %1$s. Broken: %1$s';
```

Comment: that solution would work for me if it is possible to: `try { sprintf($bad_template, $param); } catch(Exception $ex) { /* handle */ }` I could then tell client to use alternative placeholder and have an appropriate error message shown on input of custom greeting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, you validate their input to make sure that they've submitted a valid string

`if(substr_count($greeting_template, '%s') > 1) { //handle error }`